# Can one force a Odd Parity Pin Encryption Key using a Thales HSM?

Tags: cryptography

I need to generate a odd parity pin encryption key. I can generate a key type 001, LMK scheme U not encrypted under a ZMK as it's for local use. However when i verify the parity of the key using key parity verification tools i doesn't appear to be odd.

Is there a way i can enforce the parity during key generation process or by means of changing my HSM configs/hsm security settings prior to generating the key?

Comment: That's very specific, you may be better off asking Thales. This doesn't sound like something that would be configurable but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

Thales payShield HSM's always force odd parity on 3DES keys.

If you really want to know do a hex dump on the key and look. See [Parity bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit).

Comment: Thanks Zaph, that was also my understanding that the keys are generated with a forced odd parity. I also did a Hex to binary calc to check the parity on the key and the total sum was an even parity. Perhaps it's better to pose this question to Thales as suggested by Maarten above. Thanks guys, much appreciated.

Comment: @CryptoNoob Some more information on how you are generation the key would help. Or email me.

Comment: Hi Zaph, the key is generated using KG console command, double length key type 001, LMK scheme U, (if zmk is used, its scheme is X) but in this instance no ZMK is required. Another approach i tried was to generate 3 components of key type 001 same params as above then XOR the 3 to derive an encrypted key using FK command if not mistaken, as i'm not in front of the console now.

Comment: just to expand on the approach used to determine the parity, i'll use the first few bits of a fictitious key to demonstrate: Key: B2C9 F1A3 Cxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx and parity check:       B2 in binary = 1011 0010 (even), C9 binary =1100 1001 (even), F1 binary =1111 0001 (odd). Unless the problem lies with the very method I'm using to determine parity